# Prove that $\pi_{2n+1}(\mathbb CP^n) \cong \mathbb Z$ using the mapping cone

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $f : S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb C P^n$ be a continuous map and $X := \mathrm{Cone}(S^{2n+1}) \cup_f \mathbb C P^n$.
We have the following long exact sequence:
$$\cdots \rightarrow \pi_{2n+2}(X) \rightarrow \pi_{2n+2}(X, \mathbb C P^n) \rightarrow \pi_{2n+1}(\mathbb C P^n) \rightarrow \pi_{2n+1}(X) \rightarrow \pi_{2n+1}(X, \mathbb C P^n) \rightarrow \cdots$$

My guess is that $\pi_{2n+2}(X, \mathbb C P^n) \cong \pi_{2n+1}(S^{2n+1}) \cong \mathbb Z$ and $\pi_{2n+2}(X) = \pi_{2n+1}(X) = 0$, which would imply $\pi_{2n+1}(\mathbb C P^n) \cong \mathbb Z$.

Is my guess correct? If so, could you help me with proving these?

Comment: What is $f$?   ////

Comment: @АрсенийКряжевiswithUkraine $f : S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb C P^n$ is a continuous map. So, $X$ is obtained by gluing $\mathrm{Cone}(S^{2n+1})$ to $\mathbb C P^n$, where $f$ describes how we are gluing.

Comment: Is $f$ any continuous map or is it the standard map $S^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{CP}^n$ which sends $(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n)\in S^{2n+1}$ to $[x_1+y_1i:\dots:x_n+y_ni]\in\mathbb{CP}^n$?